# I want to expand the column to fit the screen if there is no other column

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. I get data from json. I can have maximum 6 tables which i all have put in one row like below.

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div> (table one)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div> (table two)

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div> (table three)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div> (table four)

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div> (table five)
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"></div> (table six)
    </div>
```

I want four to be wide open fitting the screen like having sum of 12 when there is no table three. How can i do that?

Comment: when you loop through the json, check if the table is empty and if so, change the class of the col you want to be full width to `col-sm-12`

Answer (score 0):

find number of table / 12 to get col. prob need to do a remainder check to do offset or something just in case number of table is 5... anyway
that should get you an ideas to start.   a

```
var tableCount = $('table').length; 
var maxColCount = 12; 
var rowWidth = maxCol/tableCount // eg 4 table / 12 row = 3 

var str = ' <div class="row">'; 
for(var i = 0; i < tableCount; i++) {
    str .= '<div class="col-sm-'+ rowWidth +' col-xs-12"></div>';
}
var str .=  '</div>';

consoloe.log(str);
```

PS: opps i did't see the json part...... anyhow....